# Add min and max for input type number with php (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, input, woocommerce

I need to set min="1000" and max="10000" for input type number. Tell me please what do I need to add "'type' => 'number'," to the following code?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'genius_product_price_input', 9 );
  
function genius_product_price_input() {
   global $product;
   if ( 100 !== $product->get_id() ) return;
   woocommerce_form_field( 'set_price', array(
      'type' => 'number',
      'required' => true,
      'placeholder'  => 'Min. 1000, max. 10000',
      'label' => 'Label text',
   ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'genius_product_price_input', 9 );
  
function genius_product_price_input() {
   global $product;
   if ( 100 !== $product->get_id() ) return;
   woocommerce_form_field( 'set_price', array(
      'type' => 'number',
      'required' => true,
      'placeholder'  => 'Min. 1000, max. 10000',
      'label' => 'Label text',
      'custom_attributes' => ['min' => 1000, 'max' => 10000], // this is added
   ));
}
```

I'm based on the documentation: https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/woocommerce_form_field.html